# Jruby sinatra app routing issue within the post route handler ( warbler generated war file sub-uri deployment )

Tags: ruby, sinatra, jruby, war

I implemented a small jruby sinatra app and if i run it directly on
WEBrick locally all the routings work perfectly. However when I deploy
the war file (i use warbler) to a server instance (like
"example.com/myapp" or "localhost:8080/myapp") I have routing
issues within the post requests.

### For example:

```
get '/login' do
   slim :login
end


post  '/login' do
  session.clear
  login_correct? = check_password (params[:user], params[:pass])

  if(login_correct?)
    session[:user] = params[:user]
    redirect to('/')
  else
    redirect to('/login')
  end
end


get '/redirect' do
  redirect to('/login')
end
```

Here the 3rd route handler  (get '/redirect' do ..) redirects to
localhost:8080/myapp/login properly with status code 303, however 2nd route handler redirects
to localhost:8080/login with status code 404.

What should i do so that redirections in post route handler works
properly when i deploy the app?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE on Solution:** After checking the code again and again I realized that  the problem was me using `form action = '/login'`  in slim:login instead of  `form action=               "#{url('/login')}"`. So it wasn't even handled by the post route handler since the post request was sent to localhost:8080/login but I thought it was route handler who is redirecting it to there..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try setting **`set :prefixed_redirects, true`** with Sinatra

(it should than use `rack.env['SCRIPT_NAME']` with redirects)

**UPDATE:** even without the `set :prefixed_redirects, true` (default is `false`) works perfectly fine under Trinidad (which should behave the same as Warbler since bot use JRuby-Rack) ... `request.env['SCRIPT_NAME']` is set to the `/context_path` correctly.

I would try updating (if they're not the latest) JRuby-Rack/Warbler as well as Sinatra as a last resort, otherwise this probably needs a detailed look at what's going on (esp. if SCRIPT_NAME is set correctly).

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. Still it shows the same behavior.

Comment: is `rack.env['SCRIPT_NAME']` set - maybe post how does your request's env look like before the redirect call ...

Comment: I just checked rack.env['SCRIPT_NAME'] and it is set correctly so I realized that when i use **redirect to('/login')**  inside a get route handler it works properly. The problem is with the post route handlers.                                                                      `post '/login' do` 
   `redirect to('/login') if password_not_correct`
   `redirect to('/') `                                                                `end`                                                                       this route handler redirects to example.com/login instead of example.com/myapp/login

Comment: Redirection works when i run the app directly without deploying.Sorry for bad editing by the way. Since it doesn't look nice i re-write the actual problem above in the original post. THANKS!

Comment: thax, updating the answer is much better - I'm dealing with something similar with JRuby-Rack so I'll try out, but in the end it might be an issue with Sinatra/Rack (with Rails it works fine due `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT`)

Comment: Thanks for your opinions @kares. I realized that i wasn't using url() helper method in the html form. (I updated the question and answer above.)